Show that $\mu_1 \perp \mu_2$, when $\mu_2(A) \ge \int_A \phi d\mu_1$, for each $A \in \Sigma$
Let $(X, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space and $\mu_1, \mu_2$ two measures defined over $\Sigma$. Suppose that $\phi \equiv 0$ (the constant cero) is the unique measurable function such that $\mu_2(A) \ge \int_A \phi d\mu_1$, for each $A \in \Sigma$. Show that $\mu_1 \perp \mu_2$.
I will denote as $\mathscr{M}(X, \Sigma)$ to the set of all measurable functions in the measurable space $(X, \Sigma)$.
I can't find an appropriate argument to prove this. Any help/hint is appreciated. Here is what I've done:
Proof.
We know that $\mu_1 \perp \mu_2$ iff for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $F \in \Sigma$ such that $\mu_1(F) < \epsilon$ and $\mu_2(X \setminus F) < \epsilon$. So, to reach a contradiction, suppose that there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $F \in \Sigma$, $\mu_1(F) \ge \epsilon$ or $\mu_2(X \setminus F) \ge \epsilon$.
Since $\phi$ is the unique measurable function such that, for each $A \in \Sigma$, $\mu_2(E) \ge \int_A f d\mu_1$, for the function $\mathbb{1}_{X} \in \mathscr{M}(X, \Sigma)$, there is some $A_1 \in \Sigma$ such that
$$\mu_2(A_1) < \int_{A_1} \mathbb{1}_{X} d\mu_1 = \mu_1(A_1)$$
Now, for $\mathbb{1}_{A_1} \in \mathscr{M}(X, \Sigma)$, there is some $A_2 \in \Sigma$ such that
$$\mu_2(A_2) < \int_{A_2} \mathbb{1}_{A_1} d\mu_1 = \mu_1(A_1 \cap A_2)$$
for $\mathbb{1}_{A_1 \cap A_2} \in \mathscr{M}(X, \Sigma)$, there is some $A_3 \in \Sigma$ such that
$$\mu_2(A_3) < \int_{A_1 \cap A_2} \mathbb{1}_{A_3} d\mu_1 = \mu_1(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$$
Continuing this way, we can find a measurable sequence $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \Sigma$ such that, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $A_{n + 1} \subseteq A_n$ and
$$\mu_2(A_n) < \mu_1\Big( \bigcap_{k = 1}^{n} A_k \Big)$$

Here is another try which requires $0 < \mu_1(X) < \infty$:
Proof.
Let $\epsilon > 0$. Define $\frac{\epsilon}{\mu_1(X)} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{X} \in \mathscr{M}(X, \Sigma)$. Thus, there is $A \in \Sigma$ such that
$$\mu_2(A) < \int_A \frac{\epsilon}{\mu_1(X)} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{X} d\mu_1 \le \int_X \frac{\epsilon}{\mu_1(X)} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{X} d\mu_1 = \epsilon$$
but $\mu_1(X \setminus A) < \epsilon$ is not clear..

There is an easy proof using RND when $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are $\sigma-$ finite. I can post it if you are interested.

Let's say $\mu_1$ is everywhere infinite (except the empty set) and $\mu_2$ is a finite measure. For any measurable $\phi$ we have that ${\phi>0}$ is measurable, so unless ${\phi>0}=\emptyset$, we have that  $\mu_2({\phi>0})<\int_{{\phi>0}} \phi d\mu_1=\infty$. But isn't this an example where the preconditions of the question hold, even though $\mu_1(F)<\epsilon\Rightarrow F=\emptyset$ and therefore $\mu_2(X\setminus F)=\mu_2(X)=\text{constant}$, and therefore for some $\epsilon>0$ we have that $\mu_2(X){\phi>0}\ge\epsilon$?

@geetha290krm Yeah! It may help

@ConnFus I’m still skeptical but it is indeed working!! Thanks

By the way, you can avoid the $\epsilon$ approximation when working with mutual singularity.  The usual definition of $\mu_1 \perp \mu_2$ is that there exists $F$ such that $\mu_1(F) = \mu_2(X \setminus F) = 0$.  You can obtain this from your definition using continuity of measure, see here.

@lily thank you very much!! As the proposition was false I tried by using that alternative definition.. but thanks again!!

Proof when $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are $\sigma-$ finite:
Let $\nu=\mu_1+\mu_2$. Let $f=\frac {d\mu_1} {d\nu}$ and $g=\frac {d\mu_2} {d\nu}$. Take $\phi=\frac   g f$ when $f\ne 0$ and $0$ when $f=0$. Then $\mu_2(A)=\int_A gd\nu=\int_A \phi f d\nu=\int_A \phi d\mu_1$ when $A \subseteq \{f\ne 0\}$. When $A=\{f\ne 0\}$ we get $\mu_2(A) \ge 0=\int_A\phi d\mu_1$. These two facts imply that $\mu_2(A) \ge \int_A\phi d\mu_1$ for all $A$. Thus, $\phi=0$ which means $g=0$ when $f \ne 0$. Can you now see that $\mu_1\perp \mu_2$?

Thank you very much!! This is a very interesting result. I will mark this as the answer, but the  counter example that I was looking for  was given by @ConnFus. Thank again!
